# Not getting expected email when running cron hook

Tags: wp-cron, wp-mail

I'm following the tutorial at https://wpshout.com/wp_schedule_event-examples/

I want to ensure my cron job works and is run at approximately a certain time of day. I have inserted debug code to send an email into the code:

```
// Schedule daily event at specific time
function daily_event_hook() {
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
  $succ = wp_mail( 'me@example.com', 'Testing', 'This is a test', $headers );
  wp_schedule_event( strtotime('13:43'), 'daily', 'run_daily_event' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'daily_event_hook' );

function run_daily_event() {
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
  $succ = wp_mail( 'me@example.com', 'Running cron!', 'cron ran', $headers );
}
```

The time in `strtotime` is set a few minutes ahead of my current time. I receive an email when the `daily_event_hook` function is run when the cron job is scheduled. So I know that's working.

But when I hit a page on the site after that time, I get no eamil from the `run_daily_event` hook. The code looks good as far as I can tell. I've tried setting the time to both local time and GMT. I'm wondering if the wp_mail function is loaded when running cron. If so, how can I load it? If it is loaded, what's wrong with my code?

I need the `run_daily_event` hook to send email notifications to actual users so sending the email this isn't just for testing purposes.

Comment: Note that you are re-scheduling this cron job on every request - so you're gonna end up with an infinite number of jobs. In the tutorial you cite, the author a) only sets up the schedule on plugin activation and b) makes sure it isn't already scheduled before scheduling it.

Comment: Yeah, I realize. I just wanted to minimize the possible places the code could break. I figured out the issue. I was missing an add_action for the `run_daily_event` function.